# How can I let the button group with id=1,2,3,... to replace the <?php query = "select * from table1"?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a dropdown button group lesson1, lesson2, lesson3..., when I choose the lesson1, I want the query = "select * from table1" change to query = "select * from table2" and so on. how can I do this?"
Big thanks, I'm new to mysql.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo()">lesson1</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo()">lesson2</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo()">lesson3</a>
</div>

<?php
    $query = "select * from lesson1" ;
?>
```

Comment: If you want dynamic functions, you will have to look into Javascript as PHP only runs once on page load. Check out this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: So I need the Ajax to complete this?

Comment: Yes. You will have to create a javascript function that calls your PHP code with the desired table name. Then that can return the data you wish :)

Comment: Why do you want to switch between tables here in the first place? Are these different in structure? If not - then all of your lesson data would really rather belong into _one_ table.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX follow this example:
HTML/JS (first page):

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
   <button class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(this)" value="1">lesson1</button>
   <button class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(this)" value="2">lesson2</button>
   <button class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(this)" value="3">lesson3</button>
</div>
<script>
function foo(elem){
var choise= elem.value;
$.ajax({
                url: "load.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {choise: choise},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                }        
           });
}
</script>
```

**What the code do here:** when you click one of button onclick active function "foo" with "this"(used to take the value later), then `ajax` call `load.php` and pass the `variable` choise with `POST`.

On load.php:

```
$choise=$_POST['choise'];
if($choise=='1'){
$query = "select * from lesson1" ;
}elseif($choise=='2'){

$query = "select * from lesson2" ;
}elseif($choise=='3'){
$query = "select * from lesson3" ;
}

//other code with for example echo row and you will see result on consol log.
```

**What the code do here:** We create variable from `$_POST` then based on that we just created a `query`. Now you can do what you want with query and `echo` for example a result.
I change `<a>` to `<button>` in my example.

If you want use `<a>` change:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(1)">lesson1</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(2)">lesson2</a>
   <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(3)">lesson3</a>
</div>
<script>
function foo(elem){
var choise= elem;
$.ajax({
                url: "load.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {choise: choise},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);

                }        
           });
}
</script>
```

This change because `<a>` don't have `value`

Comment: Oh, I don't know what's happen. My browser does'nt change anything.

Comment: If you open console dev. (f12) and go to console tab, you see any error? you created new page load.php with my code? when you select with query how you fetch data?

Comment: I restart PHPstorm and It showed:    jquery.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: elem is not defined ReferenceError: elem is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:63342/WWW/publish/lesson/js/index.js:28:6)
    at j (https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: elem is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:28)
    at j (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: you change `onclick="foo()"` to `onclick="foo(this)"` on html page? and add value to button?

Comment: I just copy your code up there with no change anything. but only a don't change.

Comment: It showed: Notice: Undefined index: choise in load.php

Comment: I am sure you wrong any part of process, you use xampp?

Comment: No, I use wamp. I don't know which part that I wrong because I am new to Ajax.

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: choise` seems like you don't declare variable

Comment: How to declare it? bro

Comment: copy my second code for php and the last one for html

Comment: have you try my solution?

Comment: it's online or local?

Comment: it's local bro.

Comment: if you want sent me the two page need ajax and i can see what you wrong.

Comment: I just add these code down below the script function in the index.php in order to change the table name in the phpmyadmin database:

Comment: <?php
$lesson = $_POST['choice'];                       
$query = "SELECT * FROM".$lesson." WHERE paragraph is not null";                
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);                 
while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) :?>                      
<p><?php echo $item["paragraph"]; ?></p>                          
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: So I wonder how can I make the "SELECT * FROM lesson1" change to "SELECT * FROM lesson2" after I click the <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="foo(2)">lesson2</a>

Comment: As you can see in my code, onlick event have on () the number 2, ajax will sent it on load page and then with a simple if you can choise which of three lesson you want.